# Sorting lost in Altair layered bar chart with error bars

Tags: python, altair

I am using a custom sort for my bar chart and it works well. However when I want to add error bars to it and use a layered chart then the sorting is not taking into account anymore. I also defined `axis = None` and that is also not taking into account.

Here is an example of the data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'size' : ['huge', 'huge', 'huge', 'huge', 'huge', 'huge', 'big', 'big', 'big',  'big', 'big', 'big', 'small', 'small', 'small', 'small', 'small', 'small'],
     'weight': ['10 mg', '10 mg', '10 g', '10 g', '10 kg', '10 kg', '10 mg', '10 mg', '10 g', '10 g', '10 kg', '10 kg','10 mg', '10 mg', '10 g', '10 g', '10 kg', '10 kg'],
     'value': [3.5,2.6,5.1,6.5,2.3,4.6,7.1,2.8,6.9,1.5,2.6,2.8,6.9,2.3,4.6,3.5,2.6,5.1]
    }
)
```

Using just the bar chart works

```py
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('weight:O', title=None, axis=None, sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg']),
    y = alt.Y('mean(value)', title='Value'),
    color = alt.Color('weight:O', sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg']),
    column = alt.Column('size', sort=['huge', 'big', 'small'])
)
```

[image]

But not anymore with the error bars:

```py
error_bars = alt.Chart().mark_errorbar(extent='ci').encode(
    x=alt.X('weight:O', sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg']),
    y='value:Q'
)

bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('weight:O', title=None, axis=None, sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg']),
    y = alt.Y('mean(value)', title='Value'),
    color = alt.Color('weight:O', sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg'])
)

alt.layer(bars, error_bars, data=df).facet(
    column = alt.Column('size', sort=['huge', 'big', 'small'])
)
```

[image]

In both plots the `axis` and `title` have been set to `None` but is not taking into account in the layered chart. The weird thing is that the sorting is taking into account for the legend (see `color = ...`) but not for the x-axis (within each size).

Is there a way around this or am I not using the layered charts correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the axis in the layered chart, you should set `axis=None` and `title=None` in both layers:

```
error_bars = alt.Chart().mark_errorbar(extent='ci').encode(
    x=alt.X('weight:O',  title=None, axis=None, sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg']),
    y='value:Q'
)

bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    x = alt.X('weight:O', title=None, axis=None, sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg']),
    y = alt.Y('mean(value)', title='Value'),
    color = alt.Color('weight:O', sort=['10 kg', '10 g', '10 mg'])
)

alt.layer(bars, error_bars, data=df).facet(
    column = alt.Column('size', sort=['huge', 'big', 'small'])
)
```

[image]

You'll notice that my version of the chart has the correct sort order: this is because I'm using Altair version 4.0. There was a [bug](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5048) in earlier versions of Altair/Vega-Lite that prevented sort from behaving properly in layered charts.

Update to Altair 4.0 or newer and your sorting will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was indeed still using version 3.3